# eclipse Photon redraws on keystroke on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse, renderer, ubuntu-18.04

Eclipse Photon appears to be re-rendering the screen on every keystroke and mouse click. This results in a jumpy motion that sees the menu being hidden and the menu bar partly draw.

[image: ide after redraw]

I have attached an image that shows the effect after the refresh. You can see here that the text menu is not visible and the menu bar is partly shown.

**UPDATE:**

I have narrowed this behaviour to the constant redraw of the bottom statusbar, as can be seen in the second image.

[image]

I have added an additional image that shows the effect when the window is not full screen.

[image]

Comment: 4.7 is two releases old. Try the current 2018-09 release.

Comment: I don't know why it show 4.7 in the menu bar. It is actually the latest Photon (4.8). I have updated the question and text to reflect this.

Comment: Photon is not the latest release. Eclipse SimRel 2018-09 has been released since.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try that and provide feedback after

Comment: An upgrade unfortunately does not solve this issue.

Comment: Could be related to the theme being used (either in Ubuntu or eclipse, though it looks like the default eclipse theme).

Comment: Is it the same if you do `export SWT_GTK3=0` vs. `export SWT_GTK3=1` before starting Eclipse from the command line?